# How to open chat page of WhatsApp using my own android application?

Tags: whatsapp

I want to send message to multiple people using my android application ,but for that I required to open Broadcast list option on chat page.so how to open chat page using android application?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```